# Display contents of text file in MATLAB shell

Tags: matlab, text-files

I'm using MATLAB under Windows, and trying to display (dump) the contents of a text file in the command shell. It seems like overkill to open a small file in the editor, or to load the file to use `disp`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`type`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/type.html) and specify the explicit file name (including the extension), for instance:

```
type('myfile.txt')
```

Comment: That is about as concise and on-target as an answer can get!

Comment: Nice. I found `!more myfile.txt` works also, but is OS dependent.

Answer (score 0):

As well as `type`, there's also [`dbtype`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/dbtype.html) which lets you pick a start and end range to print, and shows line numbers - handy for listing source files.